# Browser or tool to support GPS-based HTML5 location

Tags: windows-7, web-browser, gps

It seems that when using a website that makes use of HTML5 geolocation, it only uses network-based location. We have laptops with high accuracy GNSS receivers, but they go wasted because of this.

Is there a browser or an extension or other tool that can make use of the actual GNSS data to geolocate via HTML5?

This applies to a laptop computer with Win7. It seems this is natively supported on mobile OS, but not desktop-focussed OS.